# DC to AC inverter (full h bridge) with single pwm channel

Tags: pwm, inverter, h-bridge, dc-ac

I have only one PWM channel.

but I have found PWM and inverted PWM signal is required to run the full H bridge to convert DC to AC.

a square AC signal is more than enough for my application

is it possible to use a CMOS NOT logic ic to invert the PWM and give it to the full h bridge?

PWM frequency range will be 0-300Hz

also, I have found 3ns switching time NOT gates available in market
[image: somthing similar to this but with a NOT gate]

power supply source will 150-220V DC 50mA

Comment: Show a schematic

Comment: @Voltage Spike  I have added somewhat I am trying to modify also voltage and current that is going to alternate is updated

Comment: Plenty of options available! What do you need in the end? Proportional duty cycle? Proportional output voltage?

Comment: @winny I need to change duty as well as the frequency

Comment: Still doable. Can you accept input frequency = output frequency? Can you accept input duty cycle = output duty cycle?

Comment: @winny no need to be exactly same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PWM modules to control H-bridges typically have enhanced features to simplify the control.  Although you can create a complimentary signal using an inverting gate, it would still be wise to have some sort of dead time control as well to ensure high and low side switches don't turn on at the same time.